# Angular Component @Input is always empty on set

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component that has 2 inputs, one is set and one is a regular property.

```
@Input() public set value(val: string) {
        this._selectedOption =
           this._options.find(o => o[this.selectedProperty || 'someDefault'] === val);
    }
@Input() public selectedProperty: string;
```

In the above code, the selectedProperty is always empty the first time there is a set value.

This is the html:

```
 <my-component [value]="someValue"
                           selectedProperty="value"
                </my-component>
```

In other appearances of this component the selectedProperty will be empty.

How do I make the selectedProperty not be empty the first time?

Comment: For me has no sense, it work, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ntmxz5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts. Are you sure "somevalue" is a variable of parent? Remember that if you write [value]="expresion", the expresion is a variable or a constant type `'value'`

Comment: I couldn't run the stackblitz but yes, 'someValue' was a property(variable) that holds a string in the parent. I would suggest to edit the stackblitz to console log the selectedProperty in the set of value to see if its undefined and it should be.

Comment: Sorry, @misha, it's true, please forget my comment, the only solution is change the order of the declarations

Answer (score 1):

A fun answer. The order of sets in the @Inputs are the order of their declaration in the class.

So to have selectedProperty set first it should be:

```
@Input() public selectedProperty: string;
@Input() public set value(val: string) {
        this._selectedOption =
           this._options.find(o => o[this.selectedProperty || 'someDefault'] === val);
    }
```

This is generally related to how JavaScript works and in general this is the order of how angular finds the inputs in the class.

Comment: Or don't expect it to be set on property setters.  Move the code to a method and call it on init and also when set after init.

Comment: Would have to move the code to be an ngmodel kind of thing rather than nginit since it needs to execute each time the value changes